# How to SELECT objects with coordinates (east, north) from a text-file?

Tags: oracle, coordinates, spatial

at first I will describe the main-target, but I will break it down to a more simple description.
Prolog: my SQL-knowledge is not endless :-(

a) In short

- I have Oracle Spatial with a table which stores point (x/y or east/north)
- I have (different) text files which contain lists of coordinates, paired and separated with comma. Always 3 decimal places, also using trailing 0.

```
1.123,4.680
15.000,5.987
.....
```

Job: Show me all points whose coordinates are defined in file d:\data\my_coords.txt

b) In more simple details:

- Let's forget the thing with external text-files. I can copy and paste them to the SQL-file.
- I can extract the x- and y-coordinates from Oracle - they are real, single values, without trailing 0.
- I have the x-y-pairs from the text file - they are a string, paired, with trailing 0.

My idea is to do some crazy things with truncate, concat, trim, len and so on - could work.

But are there better ways? (a mentioned above - for limited knowledge..)

Comment: Yes. read up on oracle external tables.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the CSV files from the database using the External Tables feature ([see examples in the documenation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sutil/oracle-external-tables.html)).

If the CSV files are not huge, then loop through them with PL/SQL to see which have a co-located point in your existing table. Assuming you have an existing table called `my_spatial_table` with a `sdo_geometry` column called `geometry` and `key` column called `id`, and an external table called `my_external_csv` with columns `x`, `y`, it's something like this:

```
declare
table_row_matching_csv number;
begin
 for external_csv_row in (select * from my_external_csv) loop
  select id
  from my_spatial_table
  into table_row_matching_csv
  where sdo_anyinteract(geometry, 
            sdo_geometry(external_csv_row.x, external_csv_row.y,
              null),null,null)) ='TRUE';
   dbms_output.put_line(table_row_matching_csv);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

- If there may be more than one table row matching a coordinate in the CSV, then you need another inner loop.
- If the CSV files may be huge, then you are better off creating a table from the external tables, creating `sdo_geometry` from coordinates, spatial indexes, and doing a Spatial Join, which will return `rowid` pairs of co-located points.